# how to get the emulator wallpaper?

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image]

Hello guys,

We seen that in **emulator** we can set the different wallpaper,
I need those wallpapers. I just want to know that where all those wallpaper resides, where can I find that wallpapers,

One place I found is in the `sdk-windows/System-Images/android-15/armeabi-v7a/system.img`, but that is not opened at all,

I just tried to open it with `PowerIso` , but it fails

is anybody know how can get that wallpaper then let me know ......

Comment: Is there option of wallpaper when menu button is clicked?

Comment: pull the image to sdcard using adb pull and set it as a wallpaper from menu options.

Comment: Check this  http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f4/where-are-the-default-wallpapers-located-13540/

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj: thanks for +1, I just try to make creative mind.... :-)

Comment: @AndroSelva: link "http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=pla...17b1ed;hb=HEAD" is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps for latest Jelly Bean wallpapers:

1. Launch Jelly Bean in emulator.
2. use `adb pull /system/app/Launcher2.apk` . *Launcher2.apk* file will be copied to your user folder.
3. Open *Launcher2.apk* with a zip/archive tool. (File roller on Linux, for example.)
4. go to `/res/drawable-xhdpi/` in the archive, there you'll find `wallpaper_01.jpg` to `wallpaper_12.jpg`  files. These are the system wallpapers in highest resolution.

Comment: thanks for answer, but there is no images that I want, in that directory... :-(